# Disjoint Paths - Finding the maximum number of disjoint paths in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I am given a N x M matrix and I have a certain amount of sources and sinks and I need to find the maximum paths between them that do not intersect, basically two paths can't use the same vertex. To ensure that, I've set all the maximum capacities of all vertexes to 1.
I've already tried to combine the BFS algorithm with the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm using a supersource that it's connected to all sources and a supersink that is connected by all sinks  but it doesn't always return the right amount of maximum paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you could just do a simple modification to BFS, where the first source -> sink pass removes the matrix connections for each visited vertex. And then the second pass for second soruce -> sink works on this modified matrix, and so on.